# Why doesn't POP3 work when IMAP works in Thunderbird?

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, email

I'm trying to setup my hotmail account on Thunderbird but it just won't work... I've tried with IMAP and that works fine. But I want to use POP3.

[image]

To be sure that my information is correct, i have tried without changing anything. I selected IMAP instead of POP3 and then it connects without problems.

Could someone help me to understand why it's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried manual configuration with `pop3.live.com` and port `995`? check here all setting http://www.firetrust.com/hotmail_pop3

Comment: yes, I've tried that. I've actually used that exact link ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, POP was disabled on the Hotmail account. To fix this go to: *inbox>Options>Connect devices and apps with POP* in your hotmail account, and enable it from there.

*source: [Thunderbird forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=13782149#p13782149)*